# Grouping by multiple fields and counting using in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I have a Person table in database and the associated domain class looks like below:

```
public class Person {   
    
    private String firstName;
    private String secondName;
    private String city;
    private String country;
    private int age;
    private int hits;
    
    // accessors
}
```

Database table will have multiple rows for same person and I need to aggregate the hits for each using java 8.

A person is uniquely identified by following fields:
**firstName,
secondName,
city,
country**

I have written the below logic and it gives me the expected result

```
public void generateReport(List<PersonDTO> persons) {
        Map<String, Integer> personHitCount =
                persons
                        .stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(l -> getPersonKey(l), Collectors.summingInt(Person::getHits)));

        List<Person> reportRecords =
                persons
                        .stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(l -> getPersonKey(l), Function.identity(), (o1, o2) -> o1))
                        .entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .filter(e -> personHitCount.containsKey(e.getKey()))
                        .map(e -> transform(e.getValue(), personHitCount.get(e.getKey())))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

        reportRecords.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
  }

private Person transform(Person personDTO, int count) {
    return new Person(
            personDTO.getFirstName(),
            personDTO.getSecondName(),
            personDTO.getCity(),
            personDTO.getCountry(),
            personDTO.getAge(),
            count);
}

private String getPersonKey(Person person) {
    return new StringJoiner("-")
            .add(person.getFirstName())
            .add(person.getSecondName())
            .add(person.getCity())
            .add(person.getCountry())
            .toString();
}
```

I am not sure, if this is a good and performant way of doing it, as I am looping twice over persons list. Please can you suggest any improvements to this code or a better way of doing it.

Comment: Your question changed by the time I provided my solution. Could you attach also the implementation of your `PersonDTO` class?

Comment: Also, in this new version of your answer, you now have a `List<PersonDTO>` in input to `generateReport()` and then call `getPersonKey()` which accepts a `Person`...

Comment: SQL does have queries for this sort of thing, there's little point in iterating through the whole dataset when you can let the DB do the summing.

Comment: @daniu unfortunately I am getting a response from another microservice which reads the data from database and exposes an API. I read that API response and have to do this logic

Comment: @dani-vta Thank you so much for your answer. Your solution is much performant and cleaner than mine. 
Apologies, I was in middle of editing the question and you answered it just seconds before I saved the edit.

Comment: You mention "using Java 8" -> do you simply mean you want to use the Stream API introduced in Java 8, or do you actually mean you cannot use more recent features (such as records) ?

Comment: @AkashSharma I've updated my answer with an improved version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution with Double Iteration and Same Return Type

You could improve your stream by removing some unnecessary operations, like converting a DTO into a `String` and filtering (you're filtering for the keys coming from the very map you're streaming...). That would give you a more compact and readable stream.

As @daniu suggested in the comment section, a better approach would be to get the total number of hits from SQL, as the language provides aggregate functions for this purpose. However, I assume that perhaps you didn't go this way because your SQL query would look something like this `SELECT firstName, secondName, city, country, SUM(hits) FROM ...` leaving behind other fields that are not necessary for the group by but that you need to construct a `Person` instance (this is just a guess).

In this solution, I assume that your `PersonDTO` class honors the equals and hashcode contract by providing an implementation based on the attributes: `firstName`, `secondName`, `city` and `country`.

```
public void generateReport2(List<PersonDTO> personsDTO) {
        List<Person> reportRecords = personsDTO.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.summingInt(PersonDTO::getHits))) //summing the total hits by DTO, where two DTOs are said equals by firstName, secondName, city, and country
                .entrySet().stream() //streaming the map's entries
                .map(e -> transform(e.getKey(), e.getValue())) //mapping each entry to a Person with the DTO (key) and the total hits (value)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()); //collecting the Person instance

        reportRecords.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class PersonDTO {

        @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
        private String firstName;
        @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
        private String secondName;
        @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
        private String city;
        @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
        private String country;
        private int age;
        private int hits;
}
```

---

### Solution with Single Iteration and Different Return Type

I'm updating my answer to provide a second solution with a more substantial improvement where the elements are iterated only once. However, it requires changing the method's return type from `List<Person>` to `Collection<Person>` (I know that the method was void, but I assume it was printing the results instead of returning just for demonstration’s sake).

Changing the return type from `List<Person>` to `Collection<Person>` would imply generalizing to a higher interface in the class hierarchy, as `Collection` is a parent of `List`, which might not be doable if you've already agreed on a specific contract/interface with other developers. This is why I'm posting this second solution as an update and not as the actual answer.

In short, the total numbers of hits are computed using `Person` instances, instead of Integers. Basically, each DTO is used as a key, and whenever two DTOs collide (they're equal) the hits of their corresponding `Person` are combined, keeping only the resulting `Person` instance.

```
public static void generateReport3(List<PersonDTO> personsDTO) {
    Collection<Person> reportRecords = personsDTO.stream() // Mapping each DTO to a Person and using the DTO as the key
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), dto -> transform(dto, dto.getHits()), (p1, p2) -> { 
                p1.setHits(p1.getHits() + p2.getHits()); // Whenever two DTOs collide (they're equal), they combine the hits of their corresponding Person
                return p1;  //keeping the combined Person instance
            }))
            .values();  //Retrieving the Collection of Person

    reportRecords.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

---

### Demo Version

Here is a demo version at [OneCompiler](https://onecompiler.com/java/427zp7syv). In the demo, I've assumed that both `Person` and `PersonDTO` possess the same set of attributes, since there is no implementation of the DTO class attached. I've also updated the demo with the second solution.

Comment: Thank you, I learned a new and better way of doing it today. I didn't know that I can use object as key using Function.identity() and use @EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true) for comparing selected fields.

I was also no aware of OneCompiler. Thanks again.
Upvoting and marking the answer as correct.

Comment: @AkashSharma Thanks a lot. Yes, streams use a `HashMap` as the actual implementation for a `Map`. Hash data structure (HashMap, HashSet, etc.) can have any type of object as their key, as long as those objects honor the equals and hashcode contract, and remain immutable while being used as keys. Here's an interesting article by Baeldung that covers `HashMap` and how they work https://www.baeldung.com/java-hashmap

Comment: This is a good solution. I'd just like to point out that the issue of "iterating the student list twice" is still happening, just not as apparent because it's performed under the hood with the creation of first the `persons` stream, then of the intermediate `groupingBy` result.

Comment: @daniu yes, absolutely. The first solution had only a couple of improvements. I'm now providing a better solution. Thank you for pointing that out.